# Can't break out of a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm writing a terrible text-based adventure, and I can't figure out how to break this loop. I'll try to post the relevant stuff here. Please tell me if my comments don't adequately explain what I'm trying to do.

```
chained = 1
finished = 0

# home() and club() act as rooms in the game
def home():
    while chained == 1:
        # there's a way to unchain yourself that works
        chained = 0
    while chained == 0:
        print 'your are in the room'
        input = raw_input('> ')
        if 'exit' in input or 'leave' in input or 'club' in input:
            current_room = 'club'
            break

def club():
    print "this works"

# These sort of move you around the rooms.
# current_room keeps track of what room you're in
current_room = 'home'
while finished == 0:
    if current_room == 'home':
        home()
    if current_room == 'club':
        club()
```

The expected behavior is that I would enter "exit" or "leave" or "club" into the input, the home() function would end, and the club() function would start. What actually happens is that the terminal just keeps printing "you are in the room" and keeps giving me the input.

I'll post my completely unabridged code if I must, but I'd rather not, as the actual adventure isn't exactly...professional.

Comment: now what does this buggy line does                                     if current_room == 'club':
        club()

Comment: `current_room` in `home()` is a different variable from `current_room` in the main scope. You're setting that function-specific value, but it never updates the other variable with the same name in the top-level scope.

Comment: @Haidro 'finished' is a variable to make that keep looping in order to move rooms. Basically, every time you'd change rooms, you change the room variable, stop the function, then it checks the room variable, then starts the function for that room.
Edited the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I never really understood what the code was meant for here's solution that works. You haven't stated if the variable's were global or local and why would you use loops when simple **if-else** statements could be used

```
chained = 0
finished = 0

# home() and club() act as rooms in the game
def home():
    global chained,current_room
    if chained == 1:
        # there's a way to unchain yourself that works
        chained = 0
    if chained == 0:
        print 'your are in the room'
        input = raw_input('> ')
        if 'exit' in input or 'leave' in input or 'club' in input:
            current_room = 'club'
            club()

# Not sure if finished is a local or global variable
def club():
    global finished,current_room
    print "this is messy code!!"
# These sort of move you around the rooms.
# current_room keeps track of what room you're in
    current_room = 'home'
    if finished == 0:
        if current_room == 'home':
            home()
        if current_room == 'club':
            club()
home()
```

Answer (score 4):

What `break` is doing is breaking out of the loop in the `home()` function. So when that breaks, it will go back to the beginning of

```
while finished == 0:
```

And will keep on repeating that input.

You have to also supply a `break` after `home()` (and `club()`):

```
while finished == 0:
    if current_room == 'home':
        home()
        break
    if current_room == 'club':
        club()
        break
```

---

Your code is extremely messy, by the way. While loops shouldn't be used for things like this (except when you're trying to get an input of `exit` or `leave`)

You may as well get rid of the final while loop.

Comment: Which of my while loops shouldn't be used for things like "this?"

The point of the first two while loops is to make the program not end if you enter the wrong input, which I still need to add. The second one is to make sure that it constantly checks the current_room variable, which it should do if I break the home() loop, I would think.

Also, putting break after home() and club() just ends the program.

Comment: I dont think this what he is looking for. Variable current_room and chained has local vs global scope problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do make the `current_room` a global variable. Because the variable `current_room` in `home()` and the one in `while finished` has different scopes.

Something like the following is what you are trying to achieve I guess. Look up on python variable scopes

```
chained = 1
finished = 0
current_room = 'home'

# home() and club() act as rooms in the game
def home():
    global chained
    # without the following line current_room has local scope and updating its value will not be
    # reflected in the while at the end
    global current_room 
    while chained == 1:
        # there's a way to unchain yourself that works
        chained = 0
    while chained == 0:
        print 'your are in the room'
        input = raw_input('> ')
        if 'exit' in input or 'leave' in input or 'club' in input:
            current_room = 'club'
            break

def club():
    print "this works"

# These sort of move you around the rooms.
# current_room keeps track of what room you're in
while finished == 0:
    if current_room == 'home':
        home()
    if current_room == 'club':
        club()
```

Comment: I'd probably make a Game() class or similar with a `.room` property and `.home()` and `.club()` methods.

Comment: Yes thats what I would too. But the code given here is messy and he doesn't know python variable scopes